# JodaTime duration - minutes appearing as PT-138M?

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to work out the difference between two joda-time `DateTime`s in java. I have tried two approaches, and both give me the same output.

Attempt 1:

```
Minutes mins = Minutes.minutesBetween(date1, date2);
String output = mins.toString();
```

Output: `PT-138M`

Attempt 2:

```
Interval intv = new Interval(date1, date2);
String output = intv.toDuration().toStandardMinutes().toString();
```

Output: `PT-138M`

How can I find the difference **in integer minutes** between two `DateTime` variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getMinutes()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html#getMinutes%28%29):

```
Minutes mins = Minutes.minutesBetween(date1, date2);
String output = String.valueOf(mins.getMinutes());
```

Comment: Great, that worked - thanks! Seems a bit strange to me that the object `Minutes` would not return it's own value via the `toString` method - or at least have a `toInt()` method!

Comment: @Teifi: As per javadoc [`toString()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html#toString()) returns a string in the ISO8601 duration format

Comment: @Teifi: the `toInt()` method you are looking for is called `getMinutes()`. I could answer your question by reading javadoc, I have never before used the jodatime library.